# MSAA resolve into texture attachment of the same FBO

Tags: opengl

I have been using several custom FBOs. FBO-A has MSAA texture attached into which the geometry is rendered.Then it is resolved by blitting MSAA  texture attachment of FBO-A into regular tex 2d attachment of FBO-B.This procedure implies switching between multiple FBOs and it is stated in several sources that it is more performance wise to rather switch between the attachments than between different FBOs. I tried to set both MSAA texture and the regular one attached to the same FBO. But I found I can't do the resolve by blitting. If I do texture copy from MSAA to the regular one ,will the MSAA be resolved as with blitting?

**UPDATE:**

Just for those interested to know whether it's worth (performance wise) to use several FBOs vs several attachments in a single FBO.
I just did a test (NVidia Quadro 4000) and the result was pretty identical FPS (+= 15-20 frames).it is probably hardware and OGL implementation dependent though.

Comment: "*it is stated in several sources that it is more performance wise to rather switch between the attachments than between different FBOs.*" Profiling data or it didn't happen. Stop with the premature optimizations.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do now :)

Comment: Well, just ran it on both variations and got pretty no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to set both MSAA texture and the regular one attached to the same FBO. But I found I can't do the resolve by blitting.

Of course not. In order to do a blit, the source and destination framebuffers must be complete. And one of the [rules of completeness](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules) states that all of the attached images must have the *same* number of samples.

> If I do texture copy from MSAA to the regular one ,will the MSAA be resolved as with blitting?

What do you mean by a "texture copy?"

If you're talking about using the new [4.3/ARB_copy_image](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy) [`glCopyImageSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyImageSubData), then no. Again, the sample counts of the source and destination images must match.

If you're talking about [copying from framebuffers to textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Framebuffer_copy) using [`glCopyTexSubImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyTexSubImage2D) and the like, then yes, that will perform a multisample resolve.

However, you really should just do the blit.

Comment: So to make it clear, you say that I have to set a separate FBO (or hold separate texture) to blit into?